# Links are not able to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I am using a bootstrap template. (http://brybell.me/br1) The links in the bottom nav bar do not work correctly. The browser recognizes that it is a link, and you can right click and open it in a new page, but you can't click on it directly. I am unsure what the issue is, however my friend mentioned z-index?

Here is the nav html.

```
<nav class="main nav-collapse visible-desktop">

                <ul class="inline">
                    <!-- <li><a href=".home">Home</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/appstore_button.png" alt="Get the iPhone App Now!" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/googleplay_button.png" alt="Get the Android App Now!" /></a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkage" href=".our-team">Terms of Service</a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkage" href=".privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="linkage" href="mailto:breathless@breathless.com">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </nav> <!-- /nav.main -->
```

And here is the CSS.

```
header.main.fixed {
position:fixed;
background:#44606e;
top:0;
width:100%;
left:0;
height:80px;
margin-top:0;
z-index:1000000;
}

header.main {
position:relative;
z-index:10000;
height:80px;
margin-top:-80px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

header.main > .container {
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
left:50%;
margin-left:-470px;
}

a.logo {
float:left;
position:relative;
top:10px;
}


nav.main {
float:right;
}

nav.main ul {
margin:0;
}

nav.main ul li {
margin:0;
}

nav.main ul li a img {
color:#FFF;
display:block;
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
padding:10px;
line-height:20px;
}

nav.main ul li a.linkage {
color:#FFF;
display:block;
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
padding:30px 10px;
line-height:20px;
}

header.fixed nav.main ul li a.active {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

header.main .mobile-nav {
margin-top:25px;
}
```

I am fairly unfamiliar with z-index, so this is confusing for me. I see now that it must have something to do wit the 100000 z index in header.main.fixed.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :]

There is also this JS which some think may be causing issues:

```
$('nav.main a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $target = $(this).attr('href');
    $padding = $($target).css('padding-top');
    $padding = $padding.substring(0, $padding.length - 2);
    $padding = parseInt($padding);
    $position = $($target).offset().top - $padding;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $position
    }, 1000, 'easeInQuart');
});
```

Comment: Any URL at the moment, I will be linking to a regular html page...

Comment: Is there any JS on the page that attaches a handler to those links and uses a `preventDefault`?

Comment: I really have no idea...I just looked and there is a jquery.js and modernizer js. The jquery does have some preventDefault in it, but I do not know what theyre doing. I assume its for the slider functionality? I assumed this was something more to do with the zindex?

Comment: When you click on the link it throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ` in custom.js line 160

Comment: `$('nav.main a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $target = $(this).attr('href');
  $padding = $($target).css('padding-top');
  $padding = $padding.substring(0, $padding.length - 2);
  $padding = parseInt($padding);
  $position = $($target).offset().top - $padding;
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $position
  }, 1000, 'easeInQuart');
 });`

Comment: That is the navigation JS in the custom.js. The template originally was made to be a one page, so the links were supposed to act almost like anchors, however I changed this since I am not adding content besides the slides.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do with the above code?

Comment: All I want to do is have a normal navigation bar with working links. I took this free bootstrap template, which was set up as a one page site, so the links would just take you further down the page. I am not using that functionality, because I really only need the sliders. I am unsure exactly what the JS is doing, or if it is even necessary now.

Comment: Ok it seems the code is trying to scroll to a target on doing some calculations which doesn't fit in to your site. Better to comment the navigation part completely.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks so much, I figured it was trying to do something like that. I will try this later as I am not home at the moment, and trying to get this issue fixed while I am at work :p

Answer (score 1):

There is a javascript error on the page.

> (Checked with firebug)
>
> custom.js (row 160) TypeError: $padding is undefined

Wrong code:

```
$padding = $padding.substring(0, $padding.length - 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, so how can I fix this. Would it be safe to delete it?

Comment: You might want to check with whoever wrote that code, because to me, it doesn't make much sense... and doesn't look very well written either.

Comment: Ok, I agree. This was a free bootstrap template. It was meant to be a one page site, so the links acted as anchors, but I am wanting to make them normal links. Safe to delete? I guess I can try?

Comment: If you try to comment from the line 156 to line 166 (custom.js) I think you'll lose the animation on the button but the link should work

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't think I am even using any buttons that use that animation anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Y see your ! code ! and the Javasript !! is Broken !

This are your error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

inspect the element to see the problem!

This is triggered when you click in Yous  links!!

Sorry for my English ! ^^

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a CSS issue. You probably have some Javascript binding to the hyperlinks. I've tried unbinding from firebug, then the click event works.

Comment: Thanks, I will try what anpsmn said above, and comment out the JS completely where it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have prevented default event handler for the hyperlinks, that line is causing the links to go to the pages. Disabling that line should work. But what actually are you trying to do with the JS code?

Comment: Again, this was a template (I am quickly learning to never really use them to avoid issues like this) It was setup as one page..and the links were set to scroll to a specific target. I am not using it like this, and just want them to be normal links.